# Pagination of a particular action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone help `this is about pagination`

(i have an action ) in controller

```
 def foo
 end
```

now , i want to paginate that `actions outcome`( suppose those are products )

and my view is `foo.html.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem.

Add

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
```

to your `Gemfile`.

Run `bundle install`.
In your controller:

```
def foo
  @products = Product.your_custom_scope.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Lastly, add `<%= will_paginate @products %>` in your view in place where you want pagination links to be displayed.

Comment: i have 20,000 product list and i m displaying ol of them
i want the pagination must look like 
<- previous 1 2 3 .. next->
but it looks like
<- previous 1 2 3 4 5 .... 1749 1750 next->

Comment: It should be possible. Please search for it in `will_paginate` documentation:
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki

Answer (score 1):

You can use kaminari `gem 'kaminari'` for pagination.

You can get the git document [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

Your action in the controller will be like this

```
def foo
  @products = Product.order('name ASC').page params[:page]
end
```

the paginate helper method

```
<%= paginate @users %>
```

This would output several pagination links such as `« First ‹ Prev ... 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... Next › Last »`

Comment: ya this is good... worked out with the first one.....
can u check how i want the pagination in above comments